# Adding objects to ArrayList confused

Tags: java, arraylist

Currently im doing an assignment that wants me to add 4 objects to an ArrayList!

But im however not sure that understand the mechanics of this.. even though i have been reading through my book, in order to get a decent explanation!

When we create an ArrayList
we do:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And when we are creating an object, one would do:

```
loan m = new loan();
circle n new circle();
```

When im making an object, i normally go and create a class that supports the object with constructors etc.
But as far as im aware, when adding an object to an ArrayList thats not whats being done?

Do i still need to create my class "loan" and "circle" and somehow implement it in my ArrayList, through the constructors?

Im furthermore having trouble understanding if the ArrayList can distinguish between circle and loan, when these are being added? 
-- Im still thinking in array[], so i might have a troubled thinking in regards to this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I see several separate questions here.

Comment: Im sorry.. but one really leads to another. i may ask several questions, but i believe it can be answered in short, by one who is more experienced than me.

Comment: Do you understand how an `Object[]` (array) works?

Comment: Im not 100% sure i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For differentiation of your object you can use [instanceOf](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html) in your List.

Example.

```
Loan m = new Loan();
Circle n = new Circle();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(m);
list.add(n);

for(Object b : list){
  if(b instanceof Loan){
   Loan nLoan = (Loan)b;
  }
}
```

Comment: so how can you do list.add(m); without constructing the object m?

Comment: You can't. Answerer left that part out.

Comment: i see.. so when he is doing the list.add(m) 

wouldn't that be:
    list.add(m.getLoan());

Comment: m is object of Load. List is just holder, you can simple add method. It will be better if you see java docs for methods understanding.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you have an arraylist of objects that have the Object type and you are attempting to add objects of type loan and circle to said arraylist. That being said to add these objects, m and n, to the arraylist you would need to make those objects have the type Object.

Casting is done by taking the object you want to cast and creating a new reference to the object with the new datatype, and setting the old object equal to it with the wanted datatype in paranthesis as such:

```
object newN = (object)n
```